# Is the wyswyg implementation on SO open sourced?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is the wyswyg implementation on SO open sourced?

Does it include the processing during a post back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back-end is not open source, but the JavaScript Editor is: http://github.com/cky/wmd

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referencing the question/answer area where what you type and you see your answer already displayed. This is ["Markdown"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), which is open source.

I'm not sure of the processing during the postback. I'd imagine even if there there processing during the postback that there isn't much due to most of it occurring as you type.